# htaccess deny from all in specific subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a .htaccess in root public_html/.htaccess

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from .cn
```

I have deny ip from china

however I want lock one of folder `admin folder`

```
public_html/admin/
```

Is that possible to use .htaccess deny from all in specific subfolder

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is that possible to use .htaccess deny from all in specific subfolder

You could use a simple forbidden rule to deny anyone from accessing anything from a specific folder like this:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/folder - [F]
```

It would return a error 403 message like this:

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access ADDRESS on this server.
```

The above would forbidden anyone from accessing anything inside the folder `public_html/admin/folder`

Or you can simplify and just put an `.htaccess` on the folder you want to block with the following content:

```
Order deny,allow
deny from all
```

Answer (score 2):

Put a .htaccess inside that folder with`deny from all`